# When should a heap dump be taken

Tags: java, linux, memory, heap-memory

We have a java application and my query here is to know when I should be taking a heap dump for a particular JVM. On what basis should I look at the memory usage details and take the heap dump to analyse it.

I understand that each Java process has a `pid`, which when found using the `ps` command be used with the `jstat`. From the [Jstat Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstat.html), I see the below four ways to know the memory and garbage utilization details -

```
gc: Displays statistics about the behavior of the garbage collected heap.

gccapacity: Displays statistics about the capacities of the generations and their corresponding spaces.

gccause: Displays a summary about garbage collection statistics (same as -gcutil), with the cause of the last and current (when applicable) garbage collection events.

gcutil: Displays a summary about garbage collection statistics.
```

From these 4 commands and the data they give, what parameters should i look at and take a `heap dump` when some of the metrics change. Kindly clarify.

Comment: Quick answer: you would do a deeper analysis if you have a memory related problem (memory leak, excessive memory usage, ...).

Comment: agree, but i would like to understand on what parameters are looked at for taking a heap dump. Also, can memory leak be identified by the commands mentioned in the document?

Comment: @sdgd- One factor when you would want to take a heap dump is when you realize that there is a Full gc happening in the gc logs which takes sometime to complete and hence slow downs your application's response time. Also if you already suspect your application is having memory related issues, you can have a VM argument which automatically generates heap dump on out of memory error.

Comment: the above commands i mentioned in the question give two output parameters - `FGC: Number of full GC events`

`FGCT: Full garbage collection time.` can this help in what you told? the time it takes to do a full GC and the number of full GC events keep increasing ?